# Get unique rows that appear in one table but not in other table by checking two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have three tables:
File, Module and Function.

I have functions from file mssip32.dll and functions from file ncsi.dll.

I want to get all the functions that appear in mssip32.dll but **not** in nsci.dll

**IMPORTANT:**
Functions are different if their names or their modules are different.

For example:

```
ModuleA.CreateProcess != ModuleB.CreateProcess (because they have different module)  

ModuleA.CreateProcess != ModuleA.Sleep         (because have different function name)  

ModuleA.CreateProcess == ModuleA.CreateProcess (equals)
```

The functions from mssip32.dll and nsci.dll as views:

[image]

All the tables:
[image]

This is what I tried to do:

```
SELECT fu.function_name AS 'Imported Function', m.module_name AS 'Library', COUNT(fu.function_name) AS 'Usage Count'
                                FROM File as f,
                                     Module as m,
                                     Function as fu
                                WHERE f.listview_name like 'listView1'
                                AND f.file_id = m.file_id
                                AND f.file_id = fu.file_id
                                AND m.module_id = fu.module_id
                                AND fu.function_name NOT in (
                                                    SELECT fu2.function_name
                                                    FROM File as f2,
                                                         Module as m2,
                                                         Function as fu2
                                                    WHERE f2.listview_name like 'listView2'
                                                    AND f2.file_id = m2.file_id
                                                    AND f2.file_id = fu2.file_id
                                                    AND m2.module_id = fu2.module_id
                                                    )
                                GROUP BY fu.function_name
                                ORDER BY COUNT(fu.function_name) DESC
```

But the problem with this one, is that it doesn't check that the **module names** are different and the result is **incorrect**:
[image]

We are missing `ModuleA.CreateProcess` because it doesn't appear in 'listView2'.

I wanted to be able to try something like this (theoretically):

```
...
AND (fu.function_name AND m.module_name) NOT in (
                    SELECT fu2.function_name, m2.module_name
                    FROM File as f2,
                         Module as m2,
                         Function as fu2
                    WHERE f2.listview_name like 'listView2'
                    AND f2.file_id = m2.file_id
                    AND f2.file_id = fu2.file_id
                    AND m2.module_id = fu2.module_id
                    )
...
```

So if I have:

```
fu.function_name = "CreateProcess"  
m.module_name    = "ModuleA"  

fu2.function_name = "CreateProcess"  
m2.module_name    = "ModuleB"
```

It will return `((fu.function_name != fu2.function_name) OR (m.module_name != m2.module_name))`

And then the **desierd result** will be:
[image]

**CODE:**
**Table structures:**

```
CREATE TABLE File (
    file_id INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    name VARCHAR(160) NOT NULL ,
    listview_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
    type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
    recursive VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (file_id)
) ;

CREATE TABLE Module (
    file_id INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    module_id INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    module_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (file_id)
) ;

CREATE TABLE Function (
    file_id INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    module_id INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    function_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (file_id)
) ;
```

**Views structures:**

```
CREATE VIEW function_List1 AS
    SELECT fu.function_name, m.module_name
    FROM File as f,
         Module as m,
         Function as fu
    WHERE f.listview_name like 'listView1'
    AND f.file_id = m.file_id
    AND f.file_id = fu.file_id
    AND m.module_id = fu.module_id

CREATE VIEW function_List2 AS
    SELECT fu2.function_name, m2.module_name
    FROM File as f2,
         Module as m2,
         Function as fu2
         WHERE f2.listview_name like 'listView2'
         AND f2.file_id = m2.file_id
         AND f2.file_id = fu2.file_id
         AND m2.module_id = fu2.module_id
```

**EDIT:**
I found another way to solve it.
I can query listview2 to bring me all the functions with the **same** module the function from listview1 have and then check if function from listview1 is in that list.
I did it by adding `AND m.module_name = m2.module_name`:

```
AND fu.function_name NOT in (
SELECT fu2.function_name
FROM File as f2,
     Module as m2,
     Function as fu2
WHERE f2.listview_name like 'listView2'
AND f2.file_id = m2.file_id
AND f2.file_id = fu2.file_id
AND m2.module_id = fu2.module_id
AND m.module_name = m2.module_name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition will work if you replace `and` with `,`

```
AND (fu.function_name, m.module_name) NOT in (
                    SELECT fu2.function_name, m2.module_name
                    FROM File as f2,
                         Module as m2,
                         Function as fu2
                    WHERE f2.listview_name like 'listView2'
                    AND f2.file_id = m2.file_id
                    AND f2.file_id = fu2.file_id
                    AND m2.module_id = fu2.module_id
                    )
```

You can change to:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM File as f2,
                             Module as m2,
                             Function as fu2
                        WHERE f2.listview_name like 'listView2'
                        AND f2.file_id = m2.file_id
                        AND f2.file_id = fu2.file_id
                        AND m2.module_id = fu2.module_id
                        AND fu2.function_name = fu.function_name
                        AND m.module_name = m2.module_name
      ) ;
```

Comment: It gives me a syntax error: " [ near ",": syntax error ]".

Comment: @E235 syntax `(col1, col2) not in (select col1, col2 from x)` is generally valid

Comment: @E235 I've added alternative condition

Comment: @Kacper the "NOT EXISTS " worked. I also found another way, wrote it below the "EDIT" in my question.